# Javascriptのオブジェクトの書き方はどちらが主流なのでしょうか？

Tags: javascript

Javascriptを学んでおります。

書き方がいくつかあるかと思うのですが、一般的な書き方は
下記の2種類のうち、どちらが主流なのでしょうか？（これ以外の書き方もありますか？）
またそれぞれの書き方のメリット・デメリットはありますでしょうか？

サイトによって書き方がバラバラで初心者にとって
最初はどっちで書けばいいのかいまいちわかりません。

よろしくお願いいたします。

```js
function animal1(name, age, sex)  {
  this.name = name,
  this.age = age,
  this.sex = sex,
  this.getName = function() {
    console.log(name);
  },
  this.getAge = function() {
    console.log(age);
  }
  this.getSex = function() {
    console.log(sex);
  }
};

var animal2 = function(name, age, sex)  {
  this.name = name,
  this.age = age,
  this.sex = sex,
  this.getName = function() {
    console.log(name);
  },
  this.getAge = function() {
    console.log(age);
  }
  this.getSex = function() {
    console.log(sex);
  }
};

var tama = new animal1("tama" , 13, "female");
tama.getName();

var mike = new animal2("mike" , 11, "male");
mike.getName();
```

Answer (score 6):

前者**関数宣言**のメリット

- 関数式よりコードがシンプル
- ソース上で、関数宣言より上に関数を呼ぶコードを書ける

```
var tama = new animal1("tama", 13, "female");
function animal1(name, age, sex) {
  ...
}
```

後者**関数式**のメリット

- クラスのメソッドを書くには関数式にするしかなく、コンストラクタも関数式にしたほうが一貫性がある。
- 関数を名前空間内に置くには、関数宣言だと二度手間になるので関数式のほうがシンプル。

```
// 名前空間 com.example.zoo の定義
const com = {};
com.example = {};
com.example.zoo = {};
// animal2 を 名前空間 com.example.zoo 内で定義
com.example.zoo.animal2 = function(name, age, sex) { ... };
// インスタンス化
let mike = new com.example.zoo.animal2(...);
```

以上を踏まえても、**たいした違いではないのでどっちでも**好きな方を選べばよいと思います。どちらかというと前者のほうがよく見るような気がしますが、個人的な印象でしかありません。

状況が許すなら、最近はclass構文が好まれるという印象です。

```
class animal3 {
  constructor(name, age, sex) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.sex = sex;
  }

  getName() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }

  getAge() {
    console.log(this.age);
  }

  getSex() {
    console.log(this.sex);
  }
}
```